# Can not find kubeconfig file

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, remote-access

I am trying to access a remote kubernetes cluster with kubectl. In order to copy/paste cluster credentials in the kubeconfig file I tried to access with "**~/.kube/config**" command but there is an error saying "**No such file or directory**".

Could anyone please tell me why i get this error? kubectl is perfectly working.

Comment: I assume the kubeconfig does exist, have you checked the permissions? 644 is sufficient.

Comment: Just to confirm,the file that is missing is from you master? Do you have `KUBECONIFG` [env](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) setup? Is it possible that you config files are in different location? Can you try to generate the config with `kubectl config view --flatten`?

Answer (score 15):

In my case I had KUBECONFIG variable set to "~/.kube/config" in .bashrc. The file existed & had correct permissions yet it wasn't being resolved somehow. Turned out I had to use ${HOME} in place of ~. That did the trick.

Comment: I tried with this but not work. just adding --kubeconfig start working. idk why.

Answer (score 11):

If your `kubectl` works correctly against your cluster than the `/kube/config` file should be there.

You can check the location of the file with increasing verbosity level when launching the command:

```java
➜  ~ kubectl get pods -v=6

...] Config loaded from file:  /home/thomas/.kube/config ◄ ◄ ◄ ◄ ◄
...] Starting client certificate rotation controller
...] GET https://172.17.0.4:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 11 milliseconds
```

There is workaround that enables you to generate the config with `kubectl config view --flatten`:

> --flatten[=false]: flatten the resulting kubeconfig file into self contained output (useful for creating portable kubeconfig files)

There is also possibility that while boostraping your cluster with kubeadm you did not move the files accordingly to the instructions (:

- To make kubectl work for your non-root user, run these commands,
  which are also part of the  `kubeadm init`  output:

  ```sh
  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
  ```
- Alternatively, if you are the  `root`  user, you can run:

  ```sh
  export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
  ```

If you used kubectl with sudo you will be using `kube/config` from your root path.

---

For more reading please have a look at these:

1. [Configuration/Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)
2. [Configuration/Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)
3. [Mastering-kubeconfig](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/)

Comment: is there any way I could get exact path of my kube folder?

Comment: @VaibhavkumarChaudhary The command he gave above works: `kubectl get pods -v=6` (inspect the text printed -- the first line says where the config file was loaded from)

Comment: If you're using K3S/Rancher look for `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`

Answer (score 5):

to solve this issue you need first to create a cluster in your workstation. This would generate the ***KUBECONFIG*** variable set to "~/.kube/config" directory.

Or you can use --kubeconfig + path to your kubeconfig file with

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with **git bash** on **windows**.
And I ended up replacing $HOME value in the KUBECONFIG variable with the absolute path to my home dir.
i.e.

```
export KUBECONFIG=/c/Users/<my user name>/.kube/config
```

It worked for me.

Comment: underrated comment! This was the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

After Installation of [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/) there wasn't any config file on my windows 10 machine. I have created a config file and add my clusters and users info manually.

I set a new like below :

> $env:KUBECONFIG="C:\Users\Your_username.kube\config.txt"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get this error when trying to add new cluster into Argo CD because of setting multiple config files in the `KUBECONFIG` variable I get this error:

```
root@cp-01:~# ./argocd-linux-arm64 cluster add kubernetes-admin@DOMAIN.com -y --in-cluster
```

> FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Internal desc = Unable to create K8s REST config: stat /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf:/root/new_admin.conf: no such file or directory

The solution was to set only single config file (the one of the current cluster) and pass the kubeconfig file I need as an argument:

```
root@cp-01:~# ./argocd-linux-arm64 cluster add kubernetes-admin@DOMAIN.com -y --in-cluster --kubeconfig /root/new_admin.conf
```